# When I run this code only the Splitpane shows up but not the JMenu

Tags: java, jmenu, splitpane

When I run this code the interface will be split however the code I've used to make the `JMenu` doesn't show up and there are no errors. I've tried everything but nothing appears to be working.

```
public class Task1panel extends JFrame {
    public static JMenuBar setupMenu() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("menu");
        menuBar.add(menu1);
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1", KeyEvent.VK_1);

        menu1.add(menuItem1);

        menuItem1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });

        return menuBar;
    }

    public Task1panel () {
        setTitle("GUI");
        setSize(150, 150);

        //The code below creates the two panels of the UI And they are both labelled with names.
        JPanel jsp1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jsp2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Left Side");
        JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Right Side");

        //jsp1 and jsp2 work together with the code above to create the two panels of the interface by adding "J1" and "J2" this allows 
        //both sides to be labelled and appear on the UI        
        jsp1.add(j1);
        jsp2.add(j2);   

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, jsp1, jsp2);

        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        getContentPane().add(splitPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // build and show your GUI               
                Task1panel sp = new Task1panel ();
                sp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                sp.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There are no errors in this code, everything should work, however nothing appears to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a call to `setJMenubar(setupMenu());`Actually, `setMenu()` isn't called.

At the end of your `Task1panel` constructor, try adding the call as I did in the example below:

```
Task1panel () {
     //...
     setJMenubar(setupMenu());
}
```

Comment: wow can't believe that's all it took to fix it thanks for your help man appreciate it.